# Can two different kind of aggregates in Domain Driven Design have actually the same unique Id?

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

Assume that we are doing aggregate design for a ride hailing application and we have created the following aggregates: DriverAvailability aggregate, which has a value object containing the status (available/unavailable) and DriverLocation aggregate  which has a value object which contains the latitude and the longitude of the driver as well as the timestamp.

This design seems to make sense in DDD since we tend to create as smaller aggregates as possible but with enough information to enforce the actual business rules. Both aggregates seem to change independently, thus it would make sense to be different. Though it seems it does not make sense to have an unique Id which conceptually be other than the driver's Id.

So if we proceed with this design, it seems that the DriverAvailability aggregate Id as well as the DriverLocation aggregate Id should be the same Id which will be the driver Id. Is this correct in the context of aggregate design? Or DriverAvailability aggregate and DriverLocation aggregate should have their own unique Id, and just a reference driverId inside? In other words, does the use of the same Id for different aggregates (different kind) create a problem in DDD design?

Answer (score 0):

At the level of pure DDD, there's nothing saying you couldn't (assuming without loss of generality that you mean "the ID of the aggregate root", for the pedants out there): there's an implicit qualifier of "`DriverAvailability` with this ID" (in constrast to "`DriverLocation` with this ID"), kind of like how one could name their cat "Abraham Lincoln" and it's generally implicitly qualified whether we're talking about the cat or the long-dead President ("Abraham Lincoln caught four mice today" vs. "Abraham Lincoln issued the Emancipation Proclamation in 1863"); if we need to explicitly disambiguate, we do that ("my cat, Abraham Lincoln,..." or "President Abraham Lincoln...").

This level helps us to come up with a model, but we also have to put the model into practice and there, we come to how to encode a particular domain model.  Here, the answer is really "it depends": there are a lot of constraints on our encoding, some self-imposed, some externally imposed.

As to whether things like persistence and messaging layers (especially if using a framework) are going to be aware that the IDs will have to be qualified, well, that's something you have to work out with the implementations and opinionations of those.  If they insist on a particular type (e.g. string or UUID), you might have to devise a way to carry the type of aggregate as part of the ID (e.g. `DriverAvailability|${driverId}` if string; for UUID, you might have to generate them in a special way).